# Android send sms

Tags: android, android-layout

In the following code i am trying to have a text box and a button where the user would input text and on button press i would just send the SMS to the hardcoded value ,But i do not get any exception and i have included the permissions .But when i send the SMS the app closes down the error log doest have anything and i am trying this on a real device not an emulator.Does any body know what might be the problem here

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

            try {
                EditText et =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final String smstext =et.getText().toString().trim();
                sms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (smstext != "" || smstext != null)
    {
                SmsManager smsmgr=SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsmgr.sendTextMessage("+xxxxxxxx", null, smstext , null , null);

    }
    else
    {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
});

    }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Send SMS error: "+ e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

main.xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <requestFocus></requestFocus>
      </EditText>
      <Button android:text="Send SMS" android:id="@+id/sms" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
      <Button android:text="Back" android:id="@+id/back1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get some feedback on the result sendTextMessage(), you should pass an PendingIntent object on the 5th parameter of the function.

A quick online search brought this tutorial: [SMS Messaging in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

**Edit**: I re-checked the code you pasted, and you should also move the definitions of `et` and `smstext` within the `onClick` method.